# IBM Cognos not save properly the preset parameters

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a problem with the preset parameters in cognos.

I go to the properties and check in Report View's tab the "Prompt Values" saved (option "View all") and I see a specific value. Then I go to "Edit" and Cognos selects another value as default (really close to the value I saw with the option "View all").

If I clear the prompts values and make the preset again it works fine during a while, but suddenly the error appears again.

This is a known bug in Cognos?

Comment: I've seen this problem a few times. I never tracked down a root cause. I'm not sure if it's considered a known bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

The ETL process, that feeds the table, updates the value in each run.

So Cognos remembers the value, but this value is associated to a different caption in each run.

The solution was to change the way the ETL process updates the table to preserve the ids.